# C++ writing inlineable functions using classes

Tags: c++, oop, template-meta-programming

I need to write some core logic in such a way that it can be extended into multiple implementations.
Ex:

```cpp
void ComplexOp(...){
...
foo1(...); // impl specific
...
foo2(...); // impl specific
...
}
```

AFAIK I can write a C++ templated function in such a way that the content of the `ComplexOp` function will be fully inlined.

```cpp
template<typename FooFn1, typename FooFn2>
void ComplexOp(..., FooFn1 foo1, FooFn2 foo2){
...
foo1(...); // impl specific
...
foo2(...); // impl specific
...
}

// impl1 call site 
ComplexOp(..., 
[&](...){/*foo1 impl1*/},
[&](...){/*foo2 impl1*/});
```

This approach is quite complex and not very readable, because `foo1`, `foo2` methods have complex method signatures.

Alternatively, I can wrap this in a class.

```cpp
class ComplexOpImpl{
virtual void foo1(...) = 0;
virtual void foo2(...) = 0;
void ComplexOp(...){
...
foo1(...); // virtual method call 
...
foo2(...); // virtual method call 
...
}
};

class ComplexOpImpl1: ComplexOpImpl{
void foo1(...) override {/*foo1 impl1*/};
void foo2(...) override {/*foo2 impl1*/};
}

// impl1 call site 
ComplexOpImpl1(...).ComplexOp(...);
```

I am wondering if the class approach would be inlined as the templated approach?
And are there any good practices that makes it easy for the compilers to inline the `ComplexOpImpl1(...).ComplexOp(...)` call? (ex: keep/ not keep args as class members, etc)

Comment: Function templates are `inline` by default, but that doesn't mean that an instantiated template will necessarily be inlined. Virtual functions can be inlined (besides `ComplexOp`) only if a compiler can prove that only those particular functions could ever be called at the runtime. Take a look at CRTP as a possible alternative if you care about inlining `foo`s, too.

Comment: You really never should design your code in aspects of optimizing before you see real problems with real measured values.  Inlined or not is one thing but totally unrelated if part of class or free function. The compiler knows when it makes sense to inline a call, always better as you knows! So make the function defintions visible for the translation units or use LTO and forget about the rest. No need to redesign a prog with templates for nothing. But take care of using virtual calls as they typically can't be inlined as the pointed type may be unknown in compile time.

Answer (score 1):

First, using `inline` does **NOT** guarantee an actual inlining. You can force a function/method to not be inline, obviously, but you can never be sure that it will be inlined even if you say so - you have specific extensions to handle such things - like `__forceinline` with MSVC - but the classical `inline` is most an indication that you wish it to be inlined.

Sadly, even with a `__forceinline`, the function may still not be inlined... In particular, during optimizations, a function may stay normally linked because you don't have anymore available registers to perform a correct optimization, or you may reach some internal limits with huge inlined functions - this may happens in embedded development for example, if you exceed the maximum allowed footprint because of inlining.

The only (portable) way to force inlining whatever the compiler want to do is awfully ugly, since it requires to use a preprocessor macro... No need to say, that's not a correct solution unless you're fully cornered and cannot avoid to do so.

But usually, a function is **NOT** inlined when the compiler decides that the benefits aren't real. You can check a bit more [on this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=msvc-170) for example. Templates aren't guaranteed to be inlined either, even very simple templated functions... For the exact same reasons as normal functions aren't.

Inlining is usually a significant speed boost for *small* and *fast* functions called *often*, and not for *big* and *slow* functions called *rarely*.
Also, take care of *early optimizations*: 90% of the time, it's not required, and worst, it produces the opposite effect. Do your code "normally", and **IF** you have a bottleneck, **THEN** you'll try to optimize - up to search for inlining functions...
Rule of thumbs: the less and smallest `inline` functions you have, and with the least possible call depth, the more chances you have to get them really inlined. A big function called at 20th level of a call sequence would probably never be inlined... A small one in `main` is near guaranteed to be inlined.

For your problem, here are some clues:

- For complex signatures, you may use `std::function` to get "universal" function prototypes. It works very well with either lambda-expressions and normal functions. Coupled to `std::bind`, you can also target non-static methods. Obviously, you can `typedef` these types.
- Using virtual functions may not be better than compiled functions... To get the actual method address, you'll need a lookup into VMT (Virtual Method Table), so an indirection is often required with polymorphic code, then either a standard call or - if you're lucky - the inlined function is executed... If you try to optimize your code up to the point of avoiding a standard call, then using virtual methods isn't a solution.
- How much *different* `foo1`/`foo2` functions do you need? Are they parameters fixed, or different on each call? You may seek for specialized small classes binded (by reference) to parameters, then you'll need only a method with a simple signature (`void exec()`) to make the actual work. Or you can declare global lambdas for each function you need.
- If your core logic works as a cumulative process, you can do a base class, then subclass for the first step, subclass for the second, etc. and each time call the base class method to perform the "old" job before adding the new one. The major problem is that this chain is fully static at compile time. You can do it dynamically by using a "chained list" logic to get the next step through a pointer to a polymorphic class... It works very well, but there is a slight overhead to handle this chain - I personnaly like to use stream operators to perform such "chains". You may also need a "storage class" (a simple `struct` will work, as long as it's properly shared/referenced) to store all possible parameters and give it to all chained classes, each one will peek what it needs and will ignore other unused parameters.

For more details, you'll need to give some examples of *actual* code/function prototypes, because such optimizations heavily rely on your implementation and underlying algorithms.